PHP TCPDF ERROR: [8] Undefined offset: 29 using < character
I am trying to generate a pdf using the '<'character, but It shows me this error. I think the < character is the problem, because I am using html tags and they use the character to close any tag.
Do you know how can i add this character safetly?
Here is some code example:
<table>
<tr>
<th>
name
</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<u>
1<=5
</u>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

I already tried to change this character to &lt, but i didn't work.

Normally symbols like this should use &lt; rather than the actual symbol, can you show the code that is causing the problem? You did have the ; on the end, didn't you?

I found out the solution, I was move the string wich had the character between files, so , in the end file I only used the str_replace function and replace the actual character for the <
